# Filter() method is returning boolean when an array is expected

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, boolean, openweathermap

I am fetching two arrays of objects from two different APIs - one for events, and one for weather.  My ultimate goal is to show a list of events and include the weather forecast for the event start time alongside the event.

The responses are coming back just fine, but the times are in different formats.  Weather in unix, events in UTC.  I have made functions to format both of those times and they seem to be working properly.

I am running the following code and getting a returned value of `false` when I would expect an array either empty `[]` or containing a few event data objects.

```
const getEventAndWeather = (seatGeekEvents, hourlyForecast) => {
  const eventAndWeatherArray = seatGeekEvents
                   .filter((event) => formatEventTime(event.datetime_local))
                   .includes(hourlyForecast.map((forecastItem) => (formatWeatherTime(forecastItem.dt))));
  return eventAndWeatherArray
};

console.log(getEventAndWeather(seatGeekEvents, hourlyForecast));
```

To achieve my goal, I thought that I could use a filter method, with includes, while formatting the values I was comparing, but I fear I've gotten too fancy pants.  Even if I don't use this combination of methods in the end, how is the function returning `false` when a `filter` usually returns an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you have the result of `.includes()` and not the `filter()` one.

In your code you firstly call `filter()` which return an array and then you call `includes` method which return a boolean value.

Here is an example

```js
const arr = [6,55,33,14];

const result = arr
             .filter(item => item > 10) // at this state array [55,33] returned
             .includes(29) // returns false because there is no such elem
             
console.log(result) // false
```